# access inputted text from user with pyqt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

I am trying to access inputted text from user with following code:

```
class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.mytext = self.textEdit.toPlainText()
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.mainjob)

    def mainjob(self):
        print(self.mytext)
```

but i get empty string in result.

Comment: please format your identations according to your real sourcecode. matters for python.

Comment: Change `print(self.mytext)` to `print(self.textEdit.toPlainText())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting `self.mytext` when the dialog is created and at that point the text edit widget has just been created and is thus empty.  To get the current text when the button is pressed the mainjob function needs to get the text at that time.

```
class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.mainjob)

    def mainjob(self):
        print(self.textEdit.toPlainText())
```